# Unable to locate package perl(Net: & IO::Socket:)

Tags: apt, package-management, ssl, perl

When i am trying to use following command it shows following error

```
root@RR-DE-NMS-1:~# apt-get install 'perl(Net::SSLeay)' 'perl(IO::Socket::SSL)'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package perl(Net:
E: Unable to locate package perl(IO::Socket:
```

Do you have any resolution for this?

Answer (score 3):

`perl(Net::SSLeay)` and `perl(IO::Socket::SSL)`, these are not installable packages.

You need these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libnet-ssleay-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl
```

The names of the packages are based on the names of the Perl modules:

eg.

```
perl(Net::SSLeay)
  |   |     |
  |   |     |
  |---+-----+-|
      |     | |
    ---     | |
    |  ------ |
    |  |      |
libnetssleay-perl
```

Comment: Ah okay, nice to know. Or you could even use the CPAN console, but I think it's better to stay with the packages.

Comment: To easily guess the name of the debian package corresponding to a perl module, read their naming policy: http://pkg-perl.alioth.debian.org/policy.html#package_naming_policy

Comment: Text graph!  :D +1

Comment: Question: `apr` ? was a typo for `apt` ?

Answer (score 2):

Easy. Use apt-cache and search for perl, then grep for a possible package name, like so.

```
[simmel]@[mars]$ sudo apt-cache search perl | grep SSL
libio-socket-ssl-perl - Dieses Perl-Modul realisiert eine objektorientierte Schnittstelle zu SSL-Sockets
libcrypt-ssleay-perl - OpenSSL-Unterstützung für LWP
```

If you use above method you will get more entires, I deleted them, so don't be worried that you see more packages in your terminal, then I posted here.

To install the packages simply do

```
aptitude install libio-socket-ssl-perl
aptitude install libcrypt-ssleay-perl
```